# HTML: Linking Label to Input by Name Attribute

Tags: jquery, html, accessibility

I know that generally labels are associated to input elements by ID like so:

```
<label for="myElement">Element</label>
<input type="text" name="myElement" id="myElement" />
```

However, I need to associate the label to the input by name only:

```
<label for="myElement">Element</label>
<input type="text" name="myElement" />
```

I want to make sure that screen-readers associate the label with the input appropriately and it is convenient for the user to click the label and have the cursor placed in the input.

Is this something that would be best approached with jquery? If so, what would that function look like?

Comment: So why would you not use the `id` and allow the browser to properly handle this according the HTML specifications? This question reads like you understand, and appreciate, the proper way to this, but instead of doing it 'properly,' you're looking to do it in a different way. Why?

Comment: The form elements are loaded dynamically from the database using a custom template rendering engine. Currently using the element ID (pulled from DB) for the wrapper div around the input. I would prefer to adhere to ID being unique per page than to repeat it on the form input as well.

Comment: Why not just wrap the input in the label then?

Comment: @user1392897 According to your comment, you only have to prefix the "id" used in your input, for instance "input-113" while your wrapper can be named with the element ID.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [aria-labelledby attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-labelledby_attribute) so screen readers know the label is for the given input.

It would look like this:

```html
<label id="testLabel">Element</label>
<input type="text" name="myElement" aria-labelledby="testLabel" />
```

Comment: thank you very much for including this. I would mark both answers correct if possible as they each address part of the question: form focus and accessibility.

Comment: I am very glad you liked it :)

Comment: Since the question was about screen reader users, who are typically not mouse users, the accepted answer only works for mouse users and does not provide an accessible name to screen reader users. This answer provides an accessible name, which is the intent of the question. This should be the accepted answer (short of wrapping the field and label text inside the `<label>`).

Answer (score 2):

I know you have an accepted answer, and there are other answers above as well. But two points:

1. There is nothing here that requires nor warrants a jQuery solution,
2. I assume you cannot add `id` values willy-nilly (such as to your `<label>`).

As such, this option is valid HTML, does not rely on ARIA, does not rely on script, does not require you to generate unique `id` values, does not require you to add any new attributes to the existing elements, still gives you an accessible name, and still maintains a larger click/hit area:

```
<label>Element
  <input type="text" name="myElement">
</label>
```

Wrapping the field in the `<label>` element with the label text gives you the support you need without having to over-engineer it.

[edited to remove `for` attribute, because I am a twit who went too quickly]

Comment: I like the way you were going with this, but it does not work. 1-When you click the label the input won't be focused. 2-Screen readers won't read label text when input field is focused.

Comment: Oops, left the `for` attribute. Remove it and it works: https://codepen.io/aardrian/pen/NjOeyp (editing this now)

Comment: This looks good and works fine without the for attribute :) good job

Comment: I actually don't think this is good practice, after a small research I found this: [The HTML and XHTML specifications allow both implicit and explicit labels. However, some assistive technologies do not correctly handle implicit labels (for example, <label>First name <input type="text" name="firstname"></label>).](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-WCAG20-TECHS-20080430/H44.html). Maybe a mix of your answer and mine would be optimal...

Comment: Note the versions and platforms cited. JAWS is on version 18, for example (JAWS 7.1 is from 2006). Take a look at this support chart from October 2016: https://www.powermapper.com/tests/screen-readers/labelling/input-text-implicit-label-before/ I think you can be confident this will work for anyone running recent operating system / browser / screen reader combinations. Anecdotally, I have not seen anything older than JAWS 13 in years (JAWS 13 is from 2011).

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to compliment both the above answers because they're very good. Honestly, I'd probably use one of theirs or a combination of both.

Nonetheless, I do have one question, is it possible to change the dynamic ID (the one pulled from the DB as the element wrapper)? Are you able to use the autofocus attribute in the input field? For instance,

```html
<label for="myElement">Element</label>
<span id="myElementWrap">
  <input type="text" name="myElement" id="myElement" autofocus />
</span>
```

Comment: I would refrain from using this approach as I like to avoid the use of `span` and `div` as much as possible as those offer little value to screen readers and to the semantics of the code in general.

The `autofocus` will cause the input to be focused when the page loads. If this is the first input of a form and this form requires immediate attention this is probably ok. Bear in mind that screen readers will stop reading the page to read the form/input when the page loads.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: Your problem is defined more precisely in one of your comment**

> The form elements are loaded dynamically from the database using a custom template rendering engine. Currently using the element ID (pulled from DB) for the wrapper div around the input. I would prefer to adhere to ID being unique per page than to repeat it on the form input as well.

For that being solved, you only have to prefix your inner "id"

```
 <div id="2012"> <-- wrapper
    <label for="input-2012">Custom label</label>
    <input id="input-2012" name="input-2012" />
 </div>
```

The current accepted answer works only for devices using ARIA, not for standard users. You can also use a function like PHP `uniqid()` to generate unique id through the page

---

Original answer follows:

**Screenreaders need an `id` to associate the labels with the fields. The previous accepted answer did not help for screenreader users.**

As you can use jQuery, use it to create the `id` attribute dynamically when the page load.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("label[for]").each(function() {
    var forVar=$(this).attr('for'); 
    if (!$("#"+forVar).length) {
          $("input[name='"+forVar+"']").attr("id", forVar);
    }
  })
});
```

If you do require to have different `id` attributes not matching the `name` attribute (for instance if you reuse the same `name` attribute for different form within the same webpage), you can generate dynamically an id:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var cnt=0;
  $("label[for]").each(function() {
    var forVar=$(this).attr('for'); 
        if (!$("#"+forVar).length) {
        var id='ele-'+cnt++;
        $(this).attr('for', id);
        $("input[name='"+forVar+"']").attr("id", id);
    }
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do that

***1st:*** by using `$(this).next('input').focus();`

```js
$('label').on('click',function(){
    $(this).next('input').focus();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="myElement">Element</label>
<input type="text" name="myElement" />
```

***2nd:***  by `name attribute` like this

```js
$('label').on('click',function(){
    var getName = $(this).attr('for');
    $('input[name='+getName+']').focus();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="myElement">Element</label>
<input type="text" name="myElement" />
```

Comment: Both are correct answers, but I'd use 2nd option since first relies on jQuery plugin and even furthermore, sometimes input could be before label ;)

Comment: @Diego :) .. Have a great day :-)

Comment: Note that this solution, will focus the input but does nothing to properly associate the label with their related form controls: https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H44.html

Comment: Downvoting: the OQ is specifically mentions ensuring that screenreaders associate the label with the input - and this does not address that part, only the clicking-focuses-the-input part. Happy to remove the downvote if you update answer to clarify that's it's a partial fix.

Comment: Since the question was about screen reader users, who are typically not mouse users, this answer only works for mouse users and does not provide an accessible name to screen reader users.